# macOS leaks command not saving backtrace on memgraph

Tags: xcode, macos, memory-leaks

Anyone know why would `leaks` is not saving the stack backtrace.

I'm running the following code:

```
$ MallocStackLoggingNoCompact=1 leaks 2764 -fullContent --outputGraph=chanita
```

But I get the following output:

```
leaks(3032,0x10ff275c0) malloc: stack logs being written into /tmp/stack-logs.3032.109a88000.leaks.wyh5BI.index
leaks(3032,0x10ff275c0) malloc: recording malloc and VM allocation stacks to disk using standard recorder
leaks(3032,0x10ff275c0) malloc: stack logging compaction turned off; size of log files on disk can increase rapidly
leaks(3033,0x10afe65c0) malloc: stack logs being written into /tmp/stack-logs.3033.106548000.leaks.9JZ1V3.index
leaks(3033,0x10afe65c0) malloc: recording malloc and VM allocation stacks to disk using standard recorder
leaks(3033,0x10afe65c0) malloc: stack logging compaction turned off; size of log files on disk can increase rapidly
Invalid connection: com.apple.coresymbolicationd
Output graph successfully written to 'chanita.memgraph' [0.44 MB]
leaks(3033,0x10afe65c0) malloc: stack logs deleted from /tmp/stack-logs.3033.106548000.leaks.9JZ1V3.index
leaks(3032,0x700009052000) malloc: stack logs deleted from /tmp/stack-logs.3032.109a88000.leaks.wyh5BI.index
```

the process 2764 is an app running on the Simulator, if it makes any difference.

Xcode is able to generate the stack backtrace, so it seems weird. I would like to use the command-line tool `leaks` to generate it instead of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I’ll answer this myself, maybe it is helpful for someone else too.

The issue is that I need to run the application I’m checking for leaks with the environment variable `MallocStackLoggingNoCompact=1` not the `leaks` command.

Once I’ve done that the memgraph includes the backtrace.

Comment: Was MallocStackLogging already enabled for your application before?